# Dog hair in washing machine

Tags: pets

I have recently moved flats, and previous tenants of my current apartment were avid dog owners. Unfortunate consequence of this is that washing machine covers every piece of clothing with lots of dog hair. I have run it empty to clean it two times just after moving in, put the problem still persists. How can I get rid of dog hair inside my washing machine?

Answer (score 11):

Excess hair isn't *washed out* of machine with the clothes so easily. Much of the hair is simply re-deposited back in the machine reappearing in the next cycle. Your washing machine also has its own "lint trap" of sorts in the form of a drain pump filter which has to be cleaned out periodically or all that gunk/hair can work its way back into the wash cycle.

[image: Debris filter cap] 
[image: Filter gunk]

To get excessive hair and out of the washing system, start with wiping out the tub. Make sure the washing machine is *completely* dry. I suggest leaving the lid open and letting it air dry at least overnight.

Using a brush attachment, vacuum the washing machine drum and any other areas around the inside and outside of the machine where you might find fur.

Remove and clean your drain pump filter and reinstall (see the manufacturer's instruction manual for its location).

Add 2 cups of white vinegar to the washer's tub and run through an entire regular washing machine cycle (empty) using a *hot* water setting.

With the washing machine empty again, use a sponge to wipe down the the drum of the machine with a quarter cup of vinegar added to a gallon of warm water. Make sure you get the areas around any dispensers or gaskets (typically on front-loading machines only) that may be hiding accumulated debris. Use a smaller scrub brush or toothbrush if there are lot of smaller areas that are difficult to get into.

Run one last cleaning cycle through with just plain hot water (no detergent or vinegar) to get the machine ready for the next load.